# Optimal SQL email attachment storage data types?

Tags: sql, email-attachments

I'm building my own web email and want to store email attachments as optimally as possible.

Here are the general guidelines I'm trying to achieve...

1.) It's not a file-sharing service, it's email.

2.) I want to ensure *reasonably* sized attachments are successfully saved in the database.

3.) I want to minimize the amount of space attachments use in the database.

4.) I want to use neutral SQL approaches so I won't have issues in the future when I migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

5.) What is a reasonable limit? I'm thinking along the lines of 16-25 megabytes tops for a single attachment.

AOL, Hotmail, Gmail, Yahoo and others seem to encode attachments commonly as base64, a text type. Is it more optimal space wise to store attachments as a text or binary type?

I'll be happy to make any on-topic clarifications.

Comment: any reason why you can't just store the attachments on the filesystem, rather than in the db? two reasons for the filesystem would be reduced db bloat, and the ability to search file content more easily.

Comment: With a file system it's all-or-nothing with security; with a database you get the ability to use a scripting language like PHP to say YES to the intended recipient and NO to everyone else.

Comment: Just because attachments are on the file system, does not mean that they have to be exposed to the internet. I'm not a PHP guy, but I'm sure you can use it (PHP) to serve attachments that are stored on the filesystem to only the proper users. In any case, it is certainly your decision to store the data where it makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Chue, I think it's perfectly fine to store attachments in the database. In fact, I store my files in the database as well. Since all my applications already have easy access to the database, it's very easy for all my applications to access the files. But your question is about what data type.

There's only a handful of choices. Unfortunately, your requirements are conflicting. It's basically down to a binary field or a text field. Either of these will have a type that can scale up to many times your requirements.

To minimize space usage, you'll want to use a binary since any type of text encoding will increase the space used. MySQL's binary data type is either `VARBINARY` (up to 65535 bytes) or `BLOB` (unlimited). Postgre's binary type is `BYTEA`. Thus, you can't have the same type on both servers. However, it is probably a very simple migration script to convert between the two.

Both databases support a `VARCHAR` that will support your requirement. I would go with the binary format.

As for a reasonable limit, many existing services offer 10-20MB for attachments. This seems to work well for most people. You may want to consider increasing this limit as more and more people start emailing around HD videos from their phones.